# Optimizing sorted table for join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In our asset tracking system, I have the following 2 tables:

```
item
item_location_date
```

Where `item_location_date` has the following fields:

```
ild_item (FK to Item)
ild_location (FK to location)
ild_pallet (Nullable FK to pallet id)
ild_created_when (creation timestamp)
```

To get an `item`'s current location, it's something like this:

```
select *
from item
cross apply (
    select top 1 * 
    from item_location_date 
    where ild_item = itm_id 
    order by ild_date_created desc
) ild
```

This, however is relatively slow. Looking at the execution plan, the issue is with the sorting of the `item_location_date` table, it is using the correct clustered index, which I've defined as:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[item_location_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_item_location_date] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ild_date_created] DESC,
    [ild_item] DESC,
    [ild_location] DESC
)
```

However, performance is still poor. Changing the query to:

```
select *
from 
item inner join
(select * 
 from (
        select *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by ild_item order by ild_date_created desc) rn 
        from item_location_date
    ) ild 
    where rn = 1
) itm_location
on itm_location.ild_item = itm_id
```

Yields better results, changing the sort from a top-N-Sort to a normal sort.

This database is still very small and easilty fits in RAM with plenty to spare, but I'm concerned about the performance as the quantity of data increases.

Is there anything I'm missing? Do I have the index set up to return to return the results as efficiently as possible for this scenario?

Comment: I blogged about this recently [Indexing Strategies For Cross Apply](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/06/indexing-strategies-for-cross-apply/)

Comment: Your query gives you **all** items current location but you say you need “an items current location”. Is a list of all items something you really need or is there further filtering in your actual queries? The query plans and indexing strategy might be very different if there are.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson unfortunately, yes. This is for a stock list where users want to filter themselves using the row details of SSRS. I'm aware that there may be clever ways of doing this in SSRS, but I'm trying to simplify things an flatten the locations into a multipurpose view so I can abstract the implementation away and keep keep things as simple as possible for people maintaining and writing reports in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this query:

```
select *
from item
cross apply (
    select top 1 * 
    from item_location_date 
    where ild_item = itm_id 
    order by ild_date_created desc
) ild
```

The correlated subquery is first filtered by `ild_item` and then ordered by `ild_date_created` to get the `TOP 1`. With this in mind, the index you need has to have `ild_item` first and `ild_date_created` second:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_item_location_date_item_date_created 
    ON [dbo].[item_location_date] (ild_item, ild_date_created)
```

Do you really need to select all columns with `*`? If it's just a few, you could also `INCLUDE` these on the index so it becomes a [covering index](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) and reduces additional pages retrievals.

Your current clustered index is (`[ild_date_created], [ild_item], [ild_location]`), if you don't mind changing it to (`[ild_item], [ild_date_created], [ild_location]`) then it will be as fast as you could get, since it's ordered in the manner you need and being it clustered you won't require additional lookups to get the data. Make sure there *aren't other queries that depend on the current order* if you consider making this change.